# Finding a file in the User Library of OS X Yosemite

Tags: grep, osx-yosemite

I wish to find a file in the lower levels of the `OS X` file system  (Below where Spotlight searches) by content.

In other words:  I know the sting `abc12345` os in a text file someplace.
It could be in `/Library` or perhaps `/Users/joe/Library` or even `/Users/joe/Library/Caches`

How does one file the file?
I.m not sure how to use grep  (or even if it the appropriate tool for the job)

Humor a newbee to the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, type

```
find $HOME -type f -exec grep "abc12345" {} \+
```

That says... starting in your HOME directory, find all things that are files (not directories) and look inside them for the string "abc12345" and print anything you find. The `\+` at the end says to look in several files in one go, rather than one at a time.

If you want to read all about the `find` command, or any other command, type `find` in the Terminal, put your mouse over the word and right click, then left-click `Open man Page`.

Comment: The more files you have, the longer it takes. The bigger they are, the longer it takes. It has to open and read every single file...